# Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets(418,7): error MSB4131: The "IsDebugging" parameter is not supported

Tags: sharepoint, build, visual-studio-2012, msbuild-task

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to build a empty SharePoint 2013 project (added a test list).  However when I try to deploy the project I receive the following:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets(418,7): error MSB4131: The "IsDebugging" parameter is not supported by the "SetPackagingProperties" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a gettable public instance property.

I've tried commenting out various lines but it just leads to more problems.  Furthermore it then does not package the solution.

The setPackagingProperties task, as documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.sharepoint.tasks.setpackagingproperties.aspx, indeed does not include a IsDebugging property.  Therefore is the file C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets incorrect?  I'm using SharePoint Found Server 2013.

Thanks for any help - this one is doing my head in!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the solution was simple: a conflict of DLLs.

To anyone else with the same problem:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Tasks.dll DOES contain the IsDebugging property (undocumented!).  My problem was that I had VS 2010 installed with the SP developer tools.  This meant that VS 2012 was referencing the incorrect DLL version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sharepoint.Tasks.dll.  My solution was simple to therefore search the entire system for this DLL and delete all copies apart from the one referenced in the path above.

Pareto's ratio: 80% of time wasted is attributable to just 20% of problems encountered, like this one!!!